# what is the proof of this?

Tags: number-theory

**If i have** 
$$
5 \equiv 1 \mod{4}
$$
**Then**
$$
13^{2} \equiv (5^{2}) \bmod{4}
$$
$$
13^{2} \equiv (1^{2}) \bmod{4}
$$

$$
13^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4}
$$
**what is the proof of last line ?
what makes me sure that :**
$$13^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$$
**with Transitivity ?**

Comment: no I mean  the proof of last line ?

Answer (score 0):

More generally: If $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$, then $x^k\equiv y^k\pmod{n}$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Proof: Hint: $x^k-y^k=(x-y)\left(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+\cdots+y^{k-1}\right)$.

In your case, $13\equiv 5\pmod{4}$, therefore $13^2\equiv 5^2\pmod{4}$.

Comment: Hmm..why we replace 5 with 1 this what I mean I think the proof like this ;))**If 
$$
5 \equiv 1 \mod{4}
$$
**Then**
$$
5^{2} \equiv (1^{2}) \bmod{4}
$$
$$
5^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4}
$$
by Transitivity  we have $$5^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$$ and $$13^{2} \equiv (5^{2}) \bmod{4}$$ then -> $$ 13^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4} $$ true ?

Comment: Because $5-1\equiv 0 \pmod 4$ (adding 1 to both sides)...

Comment: No i'm Asking why $$13^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4} $$ and look why we replace 5 with 1

Comment: @AchRef You're asking why $5^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $13^2\equiv 5^2\pmod{4}$ implies $13^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$?

Comment: finally ... ^^ yes  what makes me sure $$13^{2} \equiv 1\bmod{4} $$  is true ?

Comment: @AchRef The transitive property: If $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $b\equiv c\pmod{n}$, then $a\equiv c\pmod{n}$. Proof: If $n\mid a-b$ and $n\mid b-c$, then $n\mid (a-b)+(b-c)=a-c$.

Comment: you mean my proof is true is like That ? $$ 5 \equiv 1\bmod{4} $$ $$5^{2} \equiv (1^{2}) \bmod{4} $$ $$ 5^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4} $$ And i have $$ 13^{2} \equiv (5^{2}) \bmod{4} $$ then by transitivity i have  $$13^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4}  $$

Comment: @AchRef The transitive property implies "$5^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $13^2\equiv 5^2\pmod{4}$ implies $13^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$".

Comment: @AchRef Always fully write the comment before posting it. Also, you used the property in my answer: $5\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ implies $5^2\equiv 1^2\pmod{4}$. Also, you used transitivity in the next step: $5^2\equiv 1^2\pmod{4}$ and $1^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ implies $5^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: ok ;) update the last line is $$5^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4} $$ $$ 13^{2} \equiv (5^{2}) \bmod{4} $$ implies $$13^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$$